# How do I load PRs from multiple repos from a SearchIssuesResult? The items have no repository IDs

Tags: octokit.net

I'm trying to find all PRs across all repos that have a given branch name. I'm using GitHub Enterprise.

`SearchIssuesResult` contains a `List<Issue> Items` property. The individual `Issue`s in that list have a `Repository` property, but it is null, and its sibling property `PullRequest` doesn't seem to have all the data populated in it.

I therefore want to load the PR directly using the `PullRequestsClient.Get` method or similar, but this needs a repository ID. I've hit this with a debugger and the `Issue` results don't seem to contain one anywhere in the hierarchy.

I can infer an owner and name from various URLs that I do have available (e.g. the `HtmlUrl` property on the `Issue`) but that seems very hacky and ugly. Is there a better way to do this than relying on URL formats?